# How to automatically add http prefix in a href using Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-directive, angular-directive-link

Is there a way in angular 5 to add the prefix http automatically if res.MyWebsiteURL do not contains it.

I would like to have a generic way to do it since I'll use at many place in the project.

```
<a  target="_blank" href="http://{{res.MyWebsiteURL}}">Visit My Website</a>
```

Is there a way to do it throught a Directive ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `s.startsWith('http://') ? s : 'http://' + s`? This is basic JS. You should be able to figure that out by yourself if you want to do something serious with Angular.

Comment: I'm trying to do it throught a directive. I think this is the proper way to do it no ?

Comment: A pipe seems much more appropriate. You just have a string as input, and a string as output.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree with the Pipe. I'll see how to do it. Thanks a lot

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer, not in the question, and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it right a way. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

**I did a PipeTransform** 

With a PipeTransform, you can modify a string element as needed. In my case, I wanted to determine if http prefix was include in the url or not. If it's not include, I'll inlcude it.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'linkHttp'
})
export class LinkHttpPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(href: string) {
    return href.startsWith("http://") || href.startsWith("https://") ? href : "http://" + href
  }
}
```

**Here is how to use it**

```
<a  target="_blank" href="{{res.MyWebsiteURL | linkHttp}}">Visit My Website</a>
```

Special thanks to JBNizet for the help

Answer (score 2):

In my case this worked fine.

component.html:

```
<a [href]="getSubdomainLink(element)" target="_blank"> 
{{element.subDomain}} </a>
```

component.ts:

```
getSubdomainLink(element: any) {
    return String(element.subDomain).startsWith('http') ? 
    element.subDomain : 'http://' + element.subDomain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double forward slash:

```
<a [href]="'//' + url">link</a>
```